# validation not working in program is you enter an invalid response and wrong alert coming up for another prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
function studentName(x) {
  while (x == '' || x >= 0 || x < 0) {
    if (x == '') {
      x = prompt('Cannot leave field blank. Enter again');
    } else if (x >= 0) {
      x = prompt('Cannot Enter a number. Enter again')
    } else {
      x = prompt('Cannot Enter a number. Enter again')
    }

  }
  return (x)
}


function studentScore(y) {
  while (y == '' || y > 100 || y < 0 || isNaN(y)) {

    if (y == '') {
      y = parseFloat(prompt("Cannot leave field, blank please enter students score"));
    } else if (y > 100 || y < 0) {
      y = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid score, please enter a score 0-100"));
    } else {
      y = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid score, please enter a score 0-100"));
    }

  }
  return (y)
}


function another(z) {
  while (z == '' || z != 'n' && z != 'N' && z != 'y' && z != 'Y') {

    if (z != 'n') {
      z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score Y or N')
    } else if (z != 'N') {
      z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score Y or N')
    } else if (z != 'y') {
      z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score Y or N')
    } else if (z != 'Y') {
      z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score Y or N')
    } else if (z == '') {
      z = prompt('Invalid Option. Enter another score Y or N')
    }
  }
  return (z)

}

var names = []
var scores = []
var redo = true
var anotherName
var redo2
var retry = true
var anotherScore
var retry2
var i = 0
var a = 1
var score = 0
while (redo == true) {
  var studentNames = prompt('Enter student name');
  var name = studentName(studentNames);
  names.push(name)
  while (retry == true) {
    var studentScores = parseFloat(prompt('Enter student score'));
    score = score + studentScore(studentScores);

    retry = prompt('Enter another score? Y/N');
    retry2 = another(retry);
    if (retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y') {
      retry = true
      a++
    } else if (retry == 'n' || retry == 'N') {
      retry = false
    }
  }
  score = score / a
  scores[i] = score
  redo = prompt('Enter another student? Y/N');
  redo2 = another(redo);

  if (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y') {
    redo = true
    retry = true
    i++;
    a = 1
    score = 0
  } else if (redo == 'n' || redo == 'N') {
    redo = false
  }
}
var message = ""
for (y = 0; y < names.length; y++) {
  alert(names[y] + " - " + scores[y]);
}
```

---

when asked if the person wants to enter another score and Y or N and i enter something x i do get a prompt that says enter another score but once i say yes instead of asking for the score it goes straight into asking if i would like to enter another student instead of asking for the score also when you enter something that should be invalid you get stuck with the same problem but a bit diffrent first off it says invalid enter another score not another student and when you enter Y for yes it stops the program a

## thanks for the help!

it would probably be best to run the program a bit to fully grasp the issue it is difficult to explain the problem.

Comment: Surely you're curious as to whether you could cut down on all that massive duplication somehow... :)

Comment: @Utkanos just curious, can you help on that(cutting down the duplication in above scenario)?

Comment: Well the most obvious thing to do is to combine your conditions that lead to those multiple, identical error messages. So rather than a separate if/else/else-if gate for each eventuality, merge them into a compound condition e.g. `if (something || something_else || something_else_again) z = prompt('Noooo...');` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is these 3 lines

```
retry = prompt('Enter another score? Y/N');
retry2 = another(retry);
if(retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
{
   ...
```

You are only using the first input (`retry`) in your `if` statement (which can be bad input). If it is bad input `retry2` will hold the valid input (but you don't use that in your `if` condition).

You are ignoring the second attempt and using the first invalid input which exits your student score `while` loop because `retry` is bad input and not `true` anymore.

You can fix this by just changing `retry2 = another(retry);` to `retry = another(retry);`

I would also suggest using separate variables for the while statement and your prompt variable.

it also looks like you will have the same problem with `redo` and `redo2`